# Opposite of Pandas melt without index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is an opposite operation to `pd.DataFrame.melt` when no index is used? In example below I need to get the `df` from `df2`.

```
>>>df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1,2,3], "b" :[4,5,6], "c":[10,11,12]})
>>>print(df)

   a  b   c
0  1  4  10
1  2  5  11
2  3  6  12

>>>df2 = df.melt()
>>>print(df2)

  variable  value
0        a      1
1        a      2
2        a      3
3        b      4
4        b      5
5        b      6
6        c     10
7        c     11
8        c     12
```

Comment: That operation is often called "pivoting."  Check out the documentation for "dataframe.pivot()" and "dataframe.pivot_table()".  There are many good answers about this on SO already.  Here's a fairly comprehensive one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `pivot` or `crosstab` or `pivot_table` or `stack` `unstack`, but before doing that you need `cumcount` get the index

```
#d=df.melt()
d.assign(index=d.groupby('variable').value.cumcount()).pivot('index','variable','value')
Out[1443]: 
variable  a  b   c
index             
0         1  4  10
1         2  5  11
2         3  6  12
```

Comment: I was hoping for something like `R`'s `dcast(df2, .~variable, value.var="value")`, but fair enough (-;

Comment: @Pepacz hah, sometime R is more easy with spread , if you are interesting , you can check tidyverse